# How to keep loaded entities in memory in .NET and EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, design-patterns, entity-framework-core

I am working on a legacy application written in .NET 2.0 and C# that's only purpose is to execute workflows (background jobs or processes).

In essence what it does is:

1. On app startup it loads all objects from DB into memory (in classes called Holder)
2. Start the processes (multiple of them) each in its own thread
3. These processes works on the data in memory (multi-threaded) so the data access is kept between locks.

[image: The process of retrieving and updating the data]

This picture depicts the process to work with the data.

I have the task to modernize this using new .NET 7 + Entity Framework and its capabilities.

Because this application is heavily multi-threaded and many of the infrastructure classes like (workers, holders, dal access) are singletons there is locking everywhere.

My wishes are these:

1. Because of multiple threads accessing the same data, I would like to get rid of those singletons. But the problem for me is where should I keep the in memory data the workflow needs to work with it.?
2. If I choose to not remove singletons, then I was thinking to use Repository pattern to hold the entities in memory, but then I they should be singletons any I don't know if this is a good idea.

My problem is where to keep the data once is loaded so that many threads can use (read, update delete) it without going to the database each time?

I need a design pattern for this, or maybe use some sort of Level2 cache for Entity Framework

Comment: Why not using distributed cache with redis https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/distributed-caching-redis-rajiv-srivastava/

Comment: So you want to load the entire database into memory at startup? And then when an entity changes, you want to persist that to the database?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I don't  want to, it is the way the application was built., Why? I suppose  is because of the performance is critical. The application can not afford losing even 100 ms of time to load/update data from db each time.  The data in the database is kept only for workflow persistence in case of power loss/error so that it can continue where it left.

Comment: @user123456, this is adding another point of failure to the application that I cannot afford.

Comment: Can you write a minimal reproducible example? I don't understand your issue. Also, EF is not thread safe. You explain you get all data in memory, what about to don't write back to database until the end with all changes? Or persist changes each X minutes?

Comment: I'm not questioning your design (well mentally, not verbally), I'm verifying I understand it correctly. Can't you just query everything `AsNoTracking()`, instantiate a DbContext when you know you need to persist some changes, attaching them to that context?

Comment: @daniherrera, Sorry can't do that. Also the persist to db is not timer based is on some checkpoints defined in the workflow process.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Ok if I mark them AsNoTracking(), but what is the difference apart EF core not tracking them anymore?

Comment: I vote to close because I don't understand the scenario.